# ssl subdomain shows content of main site but does not redirect url (wildcard cert)

Tags: subdomain, https, shared-hosting

I have a wildcard cert installed on my site `*.pcgcp.ca` which works beautifully, but when I go to my subdomain `store.pcgcp.ca` with HTTPS it shows the content of  the main `pcgcp.ca`site. I have contacted my host (it's a Bluehost shared hosting account) several times but every time they have no clue.

I tried disabling the `.htaccess` but I get the same problem. I also tried clearing cache, checking databases and files, and I have even tried this with subdomains that don't exist;  still it shows the main site content.

I can't seem to find the problem. What can I do?

Comment: What's your server setup: dedicated, VPS, hosting-only?

Comment: @AndrewLott it is just hosting-only

Answer (score 1):

As a hosting-only plan, it's unsurprising that your server is set to display the same content for all subdomains of a primary domain. You're paying for space to host *a website*, not *multiple* websites.

You could try some fancy `.htaccess` rewrite rules and return different content for different subdomains, but you may fall foul of your hosting contract if they notice, and that could leave you with *zero* websites.

Your safer bet is probably to contact your host and ask them to configure this for you (it would be at the Apache config level, below the level you can access) or set up a second hosting account for the second website.

---

On a side note, perhaps you could look into hosting your store as a subdirectory instead of a subdomain. This would allow everything in one hosting account, and give the SEO benefit of building up one website for search engines to crawl instead of splitting your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the htaccess code file in your roots folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

If that doesnt work then purchase a `dedicated IP` address from your hosting provider as hosting-only means you are using a `shared IP` address and therefore you are not allowed to use Wildcard SSL's or HTTPS'S. Sorry for the inconveniance.

Comment: I know the wild-card ssl by experience